# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.19.4.dist-info/RECORD'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall `numpy` with command `pip3 uninstall numpy` under Mac OS, but it raises the error:

```
x@bogon ~ % pip3 uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.4
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 88, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 657, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 541, in from_dist
    for path in uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 74, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 92, in uninstallation_paths
    r = csv.reader(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD'))
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1432, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1420, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(path)
  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1616, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.19.4.dist-info/RECORD'
```

To check version of `numpy`:

```
x@bogon ~ % python3
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Oct 23 2018, 14:01:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.18.0'
```

Does someone could help to fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple version of Numpy in `/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`:

```
numpy
numpy-1.14.3.dist-info
numpy-1.18.0.dist-info
numpy-1.19.4.dist-info
```

The problem happened because of `RECORD` and `METADATA` files are not available for `numpy-1.19.4.dist-info`. So I copy them from `numpy-1.18.0.dist-info`, the problem solved.